# Simplify Boolean Expression Condensing

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need help proving the following:

1. Show that $(\neg{a}\wedge\neg{b}\wedge\neg{c}\wedge{d})\vee(\neg{a}\wedge\neg{b}\wedge{c})\vee(\neg{a}\wedge{b}\wedge{c}\wedge\neg{d})\vee(a\wedge\neg{b}\wedge{c}\wedge\neg{d})\vee(a\wedge{b}\wedge\neg{c}\wedge{d})\vee(a\wedge{b}\wedge{c})\equiv(a\wedge{b}\wedge{c})\vee(\neg{a}\wedge\neg{b}\wedge{c})\vee(c\wedge\neg{d})$

using the laws of Boolean Algebra.

Thanks so much!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? You'll find that questions that demonstrate some effort to solve a problem will attract more helpful comments and answers.

Comment: I tried the distributive law, but that didn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Let me use the additive/multiplicative notation (for $\vee$/$\wedge$, respectively), uppercase letters and $A'$ for $\neg A$.
This becomes for readable when we have such long expressions.

Your result is wrong, for if $A=B=C=0$ and $D=1$, then 
$$A'B'C'D + A'B'C + A'BCD'+ AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABC = 1,$$
while
$$ABC + A'B'C + CD' = 0.$$

The right result is 
$$A'B'C'D + A'B'C + A'BCD'+ AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABC = ABD + A'B'D + CD'.$$

Use the following (easy to show):
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
X+X'Y = X+Y \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{eq:2}
(XY'+X'Y)'= X'Y' + XY. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Now, let us start by making some associations from your initial expression by using distributivity and obtain
\begin{align}
A'B'C'D &+ A'B'C + A'BCD'+ AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABC\\
&=A'B'(C'D+C)+AB(C'D+C)+(A'B+AB')CD'\\
&=(A'B'+AB)(C'D+C)+(A'B+AB')CD'
\end{align}
By \eqref{eq:1}, this becomes
$$(A'B'+AB)(C+D)+(A'B+AB')CD',$$
and taking $X=A'B+AB'$, we get, by \eqref{eq:2}
$$X'(C+D)+XCD'.$$
Now,
\begin{align}
X'(C+D)+XCD'
&= X'C+X'D+XCD'\\
&= (X'+XD')C + X'D\\
&= (X'+D')C+X'D\tag{by \eqref{eq:1}}\\
&= X'C+X'D+CD'\\
&= X'C(D+D')+X'D+CD'\\
&= (X'CD + X'D) + (X'CD' + CD')\\
&= X'D + CD'. \tag{by absorption}
\end{align}
By \eqref{eq:2}, $X' = AB+A'B'$, yielding 
$$ABD+A'B'D+CD'$$
as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

**Adjacency**

$PQ +PQ'=P$

With that:

$$A'B'C'D + A'B'C + A'BCD'+ AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABC \overset{Adjacency}{= }$$

$$A'B'C'D + A'B'CD + A'B'CD'+A'BCD'+ AB'CD' + ABC'D + ABCD +ABCD' \overset{\text{Commutation}}{=}$$

$$A'B'C'D+A'B'CD+A'B'CD'+AB'CD' +ABCD'+A'BCD'+ABCD+ABC'D \overset{\text{Adjacency}}{=}$$

$$A'B'D+B'CD'+BCD'+ABD\overset{\text{Adjacency}}{=}$$

$$A'B'D+CD'+ABD$$